# Show that the positive eigenvalue satisfies the following expression:

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$$A=\left(\begin{array}{lll} b_1 & b_2 & b_3 & b_4 \\ s_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & s_2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & s_3 & 0 \end{array}\right)$$
has a positive eigenvalue $r$ that satisfies:
$$\frac{b_1}{r}+\frac{b_2s_1}{r^2}+\frac{b_3s_1s_2}{r^3}+\frac{b_4s_1s_2s_3}{r^4}=1$$

I don't understand how to go about this without calculating the entire eigenvalues and working backwards?

Comment: **Hint:** find the eigenvector

Comment: **Hint**: what is the characteristic polynomial for $A$?

Answer (score 0):

Solved, Set:

$$Av=rv, v=(v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4)^T$$ and solve the system of equations generated for the result shown. Thanks